# Angular-Route with Spring MVC

Tags: angularjs, jsp, spring-mvc

I am new to angular-js.I am creating a sample application to understand the usage of Angular-route.My Webapp is a Spring Web-MVC Application.

I have home page with following two tabs:

- Add Record
- View Record

find below its code snippet: **home.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <jsp:include page="taskAppCommonJs.jsp"/>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="taskApp">
    <form id="taskForm" name="taskForm">  
      <table width="100%" bgcolor="black" border="0">
         <tr>
            <td>
                 <div class="main_menu">
                    <ul>
                      <li> <a href="#add">Add Record</a></li>
                      <li> <a href="#view">View Record</a></li>
                   </ul>
                 </div>
            </td>     
        </tr>
       </table>
      <div ng-view></div>
    </form>
  </body>
 </html>
```

**taskAppCommonJs.jsp**

```
<% 
  final String ctxPath = request.getContextPath();
%>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=ctxPath%>/resources/js/jquery-3.1.1-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=ctxPath%>/resources/js/jquery-1.12.1-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=ctxPath%>/resources/js/angular-1.4.8-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=ctxPath%>/resources/js/angular-route.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=ctxPath%>/resources/js/taskAppAngular.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=ctxPath%>/resources/css/jquery-ui.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=ctxPath%>/resources/css/menu_style.css"/>
```

taskAppAngular.js

```
var customerApp = angular.module('taskApp', [ 'ngRoute' ]);
customerApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
   .when('view', {
      templateUrl : 'viewTask.html',
      controller : 'activityController'
    })
   .when('add', {
     templateUrl : 'createTask.html',
     controller : 'activityController'
  });
 });
 customerApp.controller('activityController',function($scope){
    $scope.createInfo="create page";
    $scope.viewInfo="view page";
 });
```

**Spring Controller Class:**

```
@Controller
public class TaskController implements Serializable{
  @RequestMapping(value = "/createTask.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String createTask() {
     System.out.println("createTask invoked");
     return "createTask";
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/viewTask.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String viewTask() {
     System.out.println("viewTask invoked");
     return "viewTask";
  }
 }
```

**viewConfig.xml**

```
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

      <mvc:annotation-driven />

      <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources"/>

      <bean id="viewResolver"   class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
         <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
          <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
      </bean>
   </beans>
```

My `createTask.jsp` and `viewTask.jsp` is inside `/WEB-INF/view/` folder.

**createTask.jsp**

```
<p ng-bind="createInfo"></p>
```

**viewTask.jsp**

```
<p ng-bind="viewInfo"></p>
```

My problem is angular router is not working.
Can anyone provide any solution to this????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **states** in the config should be,

```
$routeProvider
   .when('/view', {
      templateUrl : 'viewTask.html',
      controller : 'activityController'
    })
   .when('/add', {
     templateUrl : 'createTask.html',
     controller : 'activityController'
  });
 });
```

Comment: I have done the modification now I am getting following error:

       Error: [$compile:tpload] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$comp   /tpload?p0=%2FcreateTask.html&p1=404&p2=Not%20Found

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `/` before view and add:
it should read:

```
.when('/view',....
.when('/add',....
```